# вылет при создании новой папки и файла c ошибкой The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: java

При создании новой папки и нового файла, создается только первая папка, а вторая нет, далее при создании нового файла происходит вылет по try - catch

```
String folName = "c:\\Patients\\" + fName.substring(0, fName.lastIndexOf("."))+"\\";
File folder = new File(folName);

if(!folder.exists())
{
     folder.mkdirs();
}

File file = new File(folder, fName);
if(!file.exists())
     folder.createNewFile();
```

Исключение такое

> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>           at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
>           at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
>           at server.TxtReadWriter.ReceiveFileFromClient(TxtReadWriter.java:84)
>           at server.TxtReadWriter.run(TxtReadWriter.java:46)

хотя по всем мануалам должно отрабатывать как минимум создание всех папок, от первой до последней. Если кто подскажет в чем подвох буду очень признателен.

Comment: А вы уверены, что имя папок корректное? И что у приложения есть права?

Comment: Имена создаваемых каталогов и файлов дайте, на которых происходит исключение. По всей видимости, содержат некорректные символы для ОС Windows

Comment: да у меня стояли |, а их винда скорее всего не воспринимает поменял на _ и все заработало

Comment: А какое исключение выкидывается?

Comment: @user197270, напишите в ответ как вы решили проблему и в чём она заключалась - это поможет будущим посетителям.

Answer (score 2):

Всё дело оказалось в том, что в имени папки присутствовал недопустимый символ `'|'`.